# To overload a package using function for checking the table has given deptno and deptname

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**PACKAGE specification:**

```
create or replace package p_overload_demo is
function dept_match(v_deptno number) return boolean;
function dept_match(v_dname varchar2) return boolean;
end  p_overload_demo;
```

**PACKAGE body:**

```
create or replace package body p_overload_demo is
function dept_match(v_deptno number) return boolean is
cdeptno number;
begin
select count(*) into cdeptno from dept where deptno=v_deptno;
if (cdeptno>0)
then 
return true;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TRUE');
else 
return false;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FALSE');
end if;
end dept_match;
function dept_match(v_dname varchar2) return boolean is
c_dname number;
begin
select count(*) into c_dname from dept where dname=v_dname;
if (c_dname>0)
then 
return true;
else 
return false;
end if;
end dept_match;
end p_overload_demo;
```

**Test call:**

```
declare
exists boolean;
begin
exists:=p_overload_demo.dept_match(22);
if(exists='True') then
dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
else
dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
end if;
end;
```

I get the following error when I test my function:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 56:
> PLS-00221: 'DEPT_MATCH' is not a procedure or is undefined
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 56:

Can anyone tell me why is this so, and how I can test my overloaded functions?

Comment: Your final anonymous block can't be what you're actually running; `exists` is reserved and will cause an error, and you're comparing a boolean to a string. With those fixed [it would throw](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a477ba261e5ee50993c61d1fb5e24a85) "PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'DEPT_MATCH' match this call". Are you sure the package spec and body are built exactly as you've shown too? Why is `v_dname` *number*? If that is `varchar2` [then it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d52d74648c079fd68b748a68eee8840b). (Also - why no indentation!?)

Comment: @AlexPoole execute p_overload_demo.dept_match(22); after invoking the package it shows the same error.

Comment: Yes, [that will](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=75659d243302639daad8221e0eff7661) - you're now calling it as if it was a procedure, not a function, and there is no procedure with that name. Your original version assigns the function return value to a variable, which is OK - so again I don't think the code you posted is what you're actually running, at least for the anonymous block.

Comment: @it's the same code and how to call a function?

Answer (score 1):

By this time you would have got your answer but still I would like to post my thoughts.

Overloading should work out of the box if it follows the rules. Besides don't use keywords reserved for oracle as variable name.e.g. exists. Using this gives error sometimes as in this case (not sure if you have noticed or not).

However I have modified the function which reduces few lines of codes and simulated the same with an anonymous block (should work with package also) and it works as expected.

```
declare
  function dept_match(v_deptno number)
  return boolean 
  is
    cdeptno number;
  begin
    select count(*) into cdeptno 
      from (select 10 deptno from dual) 
    where deptno=v_deptno;
    return (cdeptno>0);
  end dept_match;

  function dept_match(v_dname varchar2)
  return boolean is
    c_dname varchar2(100);
  begin
    select count(*) into c_dname 
      from (select 'A' dname from dual) 
    where dname=v_dname;
    return (c_dname>0);
  end dept_match;
begin
  -- with varchar
  if dept_match('A') then
     dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
  end if;
  --with number
  if dept_match(10) then
     dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
  end if;
  --negative test case
  if dept_match('B') then
     dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The PLS-00221 implies you aren't running the anonymous block you showed:

```
declare
exists boolean;
begin
exists:=p_overload_demo.dept_match(22);
if(exists='True') then
dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
else
dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
end if;
end;
```

(which has several issues of its own), but something closer to your `execute` comment:

```
begin
  p_overload_demo.dept_match(22);
end;
```

In that form you are calling a *procedure* called `dept_match`, and as the error says, there is no procedure with that name. You have two *functions* with that name, so you can call those, but need to assign the return value to something - as your original anonymous block claims to be doing, so that can't be what you actually ran to get that error.

With the other issues fixed that block:

```
declare
  l_exists boolean;
begin
  l_exists:=p_overload_demo.dept_match(22);
  if (l_exists) then
    dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
  end if;
end;
/
```

will throw "PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'DEPT_MATCH' match this call" instead, because you've declared both functions with a number argument. You are allowed to do that, you just need to be more explicit when you call them; but as your second function is trying to match a name the declaration is just wrong, and the second one should be decalred with `v_dname in varchar2`, in both the specification and body. (I see now that you corrected that in an edit to your question, but I'll leave that here anyway.)

With that corrected the block above will work.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71734dee370d026ade898002589f853a) with the function argument data type fixed, and making both calls to both functions; note you don't actually need the `l_exists` variable so I've removed it from the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party but ...There is nothing essentially incorrect with your package. With the exception that the dbms_output statements in the function can never execute as the return statement preceding them exits the function. However, they can be shortened. Since the return type is a boolean, there is no need for the IF statements, just return the comparison (the results of) as it produces the necessary boolean. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e0aeebc38e9f073f743f7110f777fe5) here. Because db<>fiddle does not support dbms_output (at least I cannot get ti to). I created a log table for messages.  (Interesting I looked at @Alex post and dbms_output seems to, wonder what I'm missing?)